# C++ namespace errors

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces

I'm running mingw-w64 on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

I'm getting errors when I try the code in a namespace, but it works fine without the namespace. The code is:

```
//foo.h

#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

namespace joke {

    extern "C" int fooStack[10];
    extern "C" int *fooPtr;
    extern "C" void fooInit();
    extern "C" void fooPush(int iVar);
    extern "C" int fooPop();

}

#endif // FOO_H
```

---

```
// foo.cpp

#include "foo.h"

using namespace joke;

int fooStack[10];
int *fooPtr;

void fooInit() {
    fooPtr = &fooStack[0] + 9;
}

void fooPush(int iVar) {
    *fooPtr = iVar;
    fooPtr -= 1;
}

int fooPop() {
    int oVar;
    fooPtr += 1;
    oVar = *fooPtr;
}
```

---

```
// bar.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace joke;

int inVar = 0;
int outVar = 0;

void Report() {
    int i;
    cout << "Pointer:   " << fooPtr << endl;
    cout << "Stack:     ";
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << fooStack[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "inVar:     " << inVar << endl;
    cout << "outVar:    " << outVar << endl << endl;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    fooInit();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Initializing" << endl;
    Report();
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        inVar = (i * 34) + 34;
        cout << "set inVar" << endl;
        Report();
        fooPush(inVar);
        cout << "Push inVar" << endl;
        Report();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        outVar = fooPop();
        cout << "Pop outVar" << endl;
        Report();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The makefile:

```
all:

    g++ -S foo.cpp

    g++ -S bar.cpp

    g++ -c foo.s

    g++ -c bar.s

    g++ -o FB foo.o bar.o
```

As I said, this all works fine if the namespace specifications are removed or commented-out. With the namespace specifications in place, the results are:

```
c:\work\gccWork\FooTest>make
g++ -S foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'void fooInit()':
foo.cpp:11:2: error: reference to 'fooPtr' is ambiguous
  fooPtr = &fooStack[0] + 9;
  ^
foo.cpp:8:6: note: candidates are: int* fooPtr
  int *fooPtr;
       ^
In file included from foo.cpp:3:0:
foo.h:9:18: note:                 int* joke::fooPtr
  extern "C" int *fooPtr;
                  ^
foo.cpp:11:12: error: reference to 'fooStack' is ambiguous
  fooPtr = &fooStack[0] + 9;
            ^
foo.cpp:7:5: note: candidates are: int fooStack [10]
 int fooStack[10];
     ^
In file included from foo.cpp:3:0:
foo.h:8:17: note:                 int joke::fooStack [10]
  extern "C" int fooStack[10];
                 ^
foo.cpp: In function 'void fooPush(int)':
foo.cpp:15:3: error: reference to 'fooPtr' is ambiguous
  *fooPtr = iVar;
   ^
foo.cpp:8:6: note: candidates are: int* fooPtr
 int *fooPtr;
      ^
In file included from foo.cpp:3:0:
foo.h:9:18: note:                 int* joke::fooPtr
  extern "C" int *fooPtr;
                  ^
foo.cpp:16:2: error: reference to 'fooPtr' is ambiguous
  fooPtr -= 1;
  ^
foo.cpp:8:6: note: candidates are: int* fooPtr
 int *fooPtr;
      ^
In file included from foo.cpp:3:0:
foo.h:9:18: note:                 int* joke::fooPtr
  extern "C" int *fooPtr;
                  ^
foo.cpp: In function 'int fooPop()':
foo.cpp:21:2: error: reference to 'fooPtr' is ambiguous
  fooPtr += 1;
  ^
foo.cpp:8:6: note: candidates are: int* fooPtr
 int *fooPtr;
      ^
In file included from foo.cpp:3:0:
foo.h:9:18: note:                 int* joke::fooPtr
  extern "C" int *fooPtr;
                  ^
foo.cpp:22:10: error: reference to 'fooPtr' is ambiguous
  oVar = *fooPtr;
          ^
foo.cpp:8:6: note: candidates are: int* fooPtr
 int *fooPtr;
      ^
In file included from foo.cpp:3:0:
foo.h:9:18: note:                 int* joke::fooPtr
  extern "C" int *fooPtr;
                  ^
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I've looked through various c++ textbooks and references, as well as several references and forums here online. I don't see any problems with the syntax.

What am I missing?

Comment: in ``foo.cpp`` you write ``using namespace foo`` while you should actually write: ``namespace foo { <your code> }``. Using namespace is not the same as defining a namespace. And also you need the ``extern "C"`` stuff inside foo.cpp else your linker will cry.

Comment: Thank you, BitTickler, but that would seem to be covered by the #include foo.h statement in foo.cpp. As I said, the code runs perfectly without the namespace specification.

Comment: You cannot declare code to be member of a namespace in a header and then not add the code to the namespace. ``namespace foo { void foofunc(); } ... namespace foo { void foofunc() {} }`` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for C linkage. But C has no namespace concept. That seems like a conflict of interest to me.

Comment: Interesting (no pun intended). I thought all I was doing by using the extern "C" linkage was eliminating the name mangling. I'm still compiling with g++, not gcc. Since my ultimate plan is to rewrite foo.s and use it without the .cpp file, I need the C linkage because the assembler doesn't recognize anything else. Is there any other way to obviate (or at least minimize) potential name collisions?

Comment: Yes, with ``extern "C"`` you define the linkage (and name mangling). You can perfectly well have c-linkage functions inside a namespace. Does not often make sense, but is legal. You cannot "cheat" a C-api to suddenly be inside a c++ namespace, though (which I feel the author of the question is attempting).

Answer (score 0):

`fooPtr` is declared both globally (in the unnamed `namespace`) and in `namespace joke`.   They are different entities.

The `using namespace joke` then tells the compiler to use names from within `joke` as candidates to match identifiers

The names `::fooPtr` and `joke::fooPtr` are both visible to the compiler when the code has a statement `fooPtr = &fooStack[0] + 9`.    The `using namespace joke` means that both `::fooPtr` and `joke::fooPtr` are valid matches.    There is no basis to to prefer one over the other, so the compiler rejects the code due to ambiguity.

Comment: Okay, now I'm really confused. fooPtr appears within the bracketed namespace joke in foo.h. It follows the using namespace joke; statement in both foo.cpp and in bar.cpp - where is it appearing in an unnamed namespace?

Comment: The declaration of `fooPtr` in foo.h is within namespace `joke`.   The declaration in foo.cpp is at file scope, not within any namespace, so is in the unnamed namespace.   The preceding `using namespace joke` in foo.cpp does not associate the subsequent declaration/definition `int *fooPtr` with namespace `joke`.